# Create dataframe from txt file

Tags: python, pandas, txt

I have a text file that has the following structure

```
"ts": "2021-01-29T00:06:46.929363"
"from": "text"
"to": "text"
"body": "text"
```

The txt file is quite large.

How can I create a dataframe with the following structure

| ts | from | to | body |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| timestamp | text | text | text |
| timestamp | text | text | text |
| timestamp | text | text | text |
| timestamp | text | text | text |
| timestamp | text | text | text |

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: can you share about 10 lines ?

Comment: they all are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file, and use each line to update a `dict`, when there is 4 keys, save them and start a new dict, finally build the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

with open("data.txt") as f:
    batch = {}
    result = []
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.rstrip().split(":", maxsplit=1)
        batch[key.strip('" ')] = value.strip('" ')
        if len(batch) == 4:
            result.append(batch)
            batch = {}

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! This returns a `key, value = line.rstrip().split(":", maxsplit=1)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

Comment: @JorgeGomes that means a line has no ":"

Comment: Yes, that was the case. Solved. Thank you for your help.